# How to get a full stacktrace from a crashed mixed mode exe/dll?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, crash, stack-trace, mixed-mode

I wrote an application in C++/CLR. It uses a native lib/dll. On rare occasions, it crashes insider this native dll. I then get a stacktrace, but only up to the managed part, the inside native part is left out. Is there a way to let it display the whole stacktrace?

I made the following test: I added a line of code inside the native dll that makes it always crash. When I run it by doubleclicking the exe, I get a stacktrace of the managed part like before. If I run it from VS2008 with a debugger attached (just pressing F5), and it crashes, I see the whole stacktrace, the managed and the unmanaged parts.

Since the actuall bug happens so rarely, I'ld like to add something to my application that somehow displays the whole stacktrace without having the users to install und run it through VS. Is there a way to do that?

Thx
   Marc

Answer (score 0):

Using Sysinternals Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), you can look at the stack of any process that is currently running. Maybe this will help you ...

Comment: While this is definitely an interesting programm I wasn't aware of, when I look at the stack of a crashed programm, no matter if it's a managed or native application, I get the following stacktrace of the main thread:

(see stacktrace in the next comment)

which isn't helping me. :(

Comment: wow64cpu.dll!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x690
wow64cpu.dll!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0xe3
wow64.dll!Wow64SystemServiceEx+0x1ce
wow64.dll!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x429
ntdll.dll!RtlResetRtlTranslations+0x1b08
ntdll.dll!RtlResetRtlTranslations+0xc63
ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe
ntdll.dll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x15
kernel32.dll!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x8e
kernel32.dll!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18
kernel32.dll!CheckForReadOnlyResource+0x175
kernel32.dll!CheckForReadOnlyResource+0x212
kernel32.dll!UnhandledExceptionFilter+0x163
kernel32.dll!UnhandledExceptionFilter+0xe0

Comment: ntdll.dll!RtlKnownExceptionFilter+0xb7
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36

Comment: Sorry, I had hoped you can see something in the stack trace that helps you. Maybe one of the other threads holds a clue, if you use multiple threads in your program

Comment: Yes there are multiple threads - but all their stacktraces look pretty similiar to the above. :/

Comment: You're looking at the 64-bit stack, you want the emulated 32-bit stack where your code is running.  This bug in Process Explorer is fixed in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly non-trivial, I can recommend to you following links:

[Fast capture stack trace on windows / 64-bit / mixed mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501602/fast-capture-stack-trace-on-windows-64-bit-mixed-mode)

[Resolve managed and native stack trace - which API to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733155/resolve-managed-and-native-stack-trace-which-api-to-use/34911963#34911963)

But what I have tried out - even if you use stack determination like this - if you get exception in native side, it will propagate as SEHException to managed side, and by when you get control on managed side - partially call stack is already lost. (Native part). It's possible to determine native call stack by when exception occurs, but this needs to be written still.

I could do this work as freelancer if needed.