# Why is RtlCaptureStackBackTrace 10 times slower in 64-bit mode compared to 32-bit?

Tags: c++, windows, stack-trace

I've recently encountered a perplexing performance discrepancy when utilizing the `RtlCaptureStackBackTrace` function between its 32-bit and 64-bit executions.

My system:

- Visual Studio 2022
- Windows 11 Professional Edition, Version 22H2, OS Build Version: 22621.2134
- Intel Core i7-9700K @ 3.60GHz
- RAM: 32GB

In Release x86 mode, the performance measurement showed:

```
Elapsed time: 617ms
```

However, when running the same test in Release x64 mode, I observed:

```
Elapsed time: 7152ms
```

This difference is substantial and, based on my understanding, atypical given that 64-bit applications often perform as well as, if not better than, their 32-bit counterparts.

Here is my test code:

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define RING_SIZE 2048

std::vector<void*> buffer;

int cursor = 0;

void test1()
{
    WORD n = RtlCaptureStackBackTrace(0, BUFFER_SIZE, &buffer[cursor * BUFFER_SIZE], NULL);

    if (++cursor == RING_SIZE)
    {
        cursor = 0;
    }
}

void test2()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; ++i)
    {
        test1();
    }
}

int main()
{
    buffer.resize(RING_SIZE * BUFFER_SIZE);

    auto beginTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    test2();

    auto endTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    auto elapsed = endTime - beginTime;

    std::cout << "Elapsed time: "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(elapsed).count()
        << "ms" << std::endl;
}
```

My questions:

- What could be causing such a pronounced performance difference?
- Are there any recommended alternatives to `RtlCaptureStackBackTrace` that are fast and stable?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; ++i)` <-- This is **not** how you do benchmarking/profiling in C++....

Comment: `std::chrono::steady_clock` is not intended for performance measurements - and also might be the cause of your problems: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/2085

Comment: @Dai The while loop is a work-around, it doesn't matter, now it's gone.

Comment: Yes, `std::chrono::steady_clock` is not intended for performance measurements. It is just a simple timer here.

Comment: You're right - I was thinking that `WORD` was re-`#define`'d on x64 but I was wrong. My mistake. I've deleted my incorrect comments (_but_ it's still better to use types that _exactly_ match the documented Win32 function's prototype, because it's entirely possible that the implicit conversion may change and break in future because Microsoft can always make breaking changes to `windows.h` in new releases.

Comment: Finding stack frames back is just a lot harder in x64.  No frame pointer in the x64 abi, so the api must use the unwind tables.  [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501602/fast-capture-stack-trace-on-windows-64-bit-mixed-mode)

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for pointing that out. It seems I missed some important information in the x64 arch, which indeed makes the process more complex. I'll delve deeper into this aspect and continue my research on the topic.